# Adding/removing value on checkbox checked/unchecked using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, math, checkbox

i am trying to make a list of options for a user to select to get a price quote, example being:

- banana check
- apple check
- biscuit unchecked
- jam check

Each option has a value banana $3, apple $2, biscuit $11, jam $1.

Total of example above $4 + $2 + $1.20 = $7.20 (biscuit is not wanted)

I want the total to update as the check boxes are ticked/unticked. The values don't seem to be adding and my code seem to lengthy if i were to add more options.

My Code http://codepen.io/Perk/pen/azpzWK

As you can probably tell i am very new to JavaScript/jQuery.

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">banana</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="css-label">apple</label><br>


<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="css-label">biscuit</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="css-label">jam </label><br>

<p>Total Cost: $<span id="total"></span></p>
```

Script:

```
$total = "";


 // Banana $4

$('#checkbox1').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $total =+ 4;
        $('#total').html( $total );
    } 
}) 

// Apple $2

$('#checkbox2').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      $total =+ 2;
      $('#total').html( $total );
    }    
}) 

// Biscuit $11

$('#checkbox3').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $total =+ 11;
        $('#total').html( $total );
    } 
}) 

// Jam $1

$('#checkbox4').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      $total =+ 1;
      $('#total').html( $total );
    }    
})
```

Comment: use `$total = 0;` and `+=` not `=+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not adding because you're using `$total =+ n` instead of `$total += n`. You're setting the `$total` value to the value specified each time. `$total =+ 11` would set `$total` to `+11` (which evaluates to the number 11).

To fix it, simply change `=+` to `+=`:

```
if (this.checked) {
    $total += 11;
    $('#total').html( $total );
}
```

### A much tidier solution

A better solution would be to add each value as the checkbox value within your markup. For example:

```
<input type="checkbox" ... value="11" />
```

Then use just one `change` event to handle all cases:

```
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked)
        $total += +this.value;
    else
        $total -= +this.value;

    $('#total').html($total);
});
```

#### Demo

```js
var $total = 0;

$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() {
    if (this.checked)
        $total += +this.value;
    else
        $total -= +this.value;

    $('#total').html($total);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" value="4" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">banana</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" value="2" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="css-label">apple</label><br>


<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" value="11" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="css-label">biscuit</label><br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="css-label">jam </label><br>

<p>Total Cost: $<span id="total">0</span></p>
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! Works Great, can't believe i got the += the wrong way around, it's too hot here! Thanks for fully reading the scenario and adding the -= if unchecked! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Try this optimised code:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GgrgvK)

```js
$total = 0;
var fruit = {
  jam: 1,
  banana: 4,
  biscuit: 11,
  apple: 2
}


$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
  if (this.checked) {
    $total += fruit[$(this).data("type")] || 0;
    $('#total').html($total);
  } else {
    $total -= fruit[$(this).data("type")] || 0;
  }


})
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" data-type="banana" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">banana</label>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" data-type="apple" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="css-label">apple</label>
<br>


<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" data-type="biscuit" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="css-label">biscuit</label>
<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" data-type="jam" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="css-label">jam</label>
<br>

<p>Total Cost: $<span id="total"></span>
</p>
```

It should work for your needs

Comment: This isn't [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). The question is *why is this not working*, not *optimise my code for me*. If you want to post a code optimisation, at least answer the question asked first.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly thanks for pointing it out. As the answer to that was already given by other people so i added and optimised code. I hope it shouldn't hurt anybody

Comment: incorrect!uncheck is not handled! I mean on uncheck the previous amount is not returned

Answer (score 0):

You can DRY up your logic by adding a `value` attribute to the HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" value="4" />
<label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">banana</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" value="2" />
<label for="checkbox2" class="css-label">apple</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" value="11" />
<label for="checkbox3" class="css-label">biscuit</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" value="1" />
<label for="checkbox4" class="css-label">jam</label>
<br>
<p>Total Cost: $<span id="total">0</span></p>
```

Then in Javascript you can use the same click handler for each checkbox. This sums the value of every checkbox on each click to ensure that no values are missed out.

```
$('.css-checkbox').click(function() {
    var values = $('.css-checkbox:checked').map(function() {
        return parseInt(this.value, 10);
    }).get();
    $('#total').html(values.reduce(function(p, c) { return p + c; }, 0));
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/sscwpewo/2/)

Comment: uncheck is not handled! I mean on uncheck the previous amount is not returned

Answer (score 0):

1. += not =+
2. initialize total to 0 , not "" . cos then += will be performed as concatenations.
3. you have to consider uncheck operation also.

   ```
   var $total = 0;
   $('#checkbox1').click(function(){
   if (this.checked) {
       $total += 4;
       $('#total').html( $total );
   } else{
       $total -= 4;
       $('#total').html( $total );
   }
   })
   ```

Answer (score 0):

use parseint
The parseInt() function parses a string argument and returns an integer
demo with checked and unchecked code

```js
$total = 0;


 // Banana $4

$('#checkbox1').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $total =parseInt($total+ 4);
        $('#total').html( $total );
    }else{
      $total =parseInt($total- 4);
        $('#total').html( $total );
    } 
  
}) 

// Apple $2

$('#checkbox2').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
      $total =parseInt($total+ 2);
      $('#total').html( $total );
    }else{
      $total =parseInt($total- 2);
        $('#total').html( $total );
    }     


}) 
    
// Biscuit $11

$('#checkbox3').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
        $total =parseInt($total+ 11);
        $('#total').html( $total );
    }else{
      $total =parseInt($total- 11);
        $('#total').html( $total );
    }  
  
}) 

// Jam $1

$('#checkbox4').click(function(){
    if (this.checked) {
     $total =parseInt($total+ 1);
      $('#total').html( $total );
    }else{
      $total =parseInt($total- 1);
        $('#total').html( $total );
    }     


})
```

```css
/*Check box*/

input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox {
       position:absolute; z-index:-1000; 
       left:-1000px; 
       overflow: hidden; 
       clip: rect(0 0 0 0); 
       height:1px; 
       width:1px; 
       margin:-1px; 
       padding:0; 
       border:0;

      }

      input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox + label.css-label {
       padding-left:27px;
       height:22px; 
       display:inline-block;
       line-height:22px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-position: 0 0;
       font-size:22px;
       vertical-align:middle;
       cursor:pointer;
       margin-top: 15px;
      }

      input[type=checkbox].css-checkbox:checked + label.css-label {
       background-position: 0 -22px;
      }
      label.css-label {
    background-image:url(http://csscheckbox.com/checkboxes/u/csscheckbox_1470d2ed405eb6fa12570883c6b38297.png);
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
   }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" class="css-checkbox" />
 <label for="checkbox1" class="css-label">banana</label><br>

 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" class="css-checkbox" />
 <label for="checkbox2" class="css-label">apple</label><br>


 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" class="css-checkbox" />
 <label for="checkbox3" class="css-label">biscuit</label><br>

 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" class="css-checkbox" />
 <label for="checkbox4" class="css-label">jam </label><br>

<p>Total Cost: $<span id="total"></span></p>
```